# Lua - Find "tags" in string?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I'm planning on using Lua patterns, unless there's a better way to do this.

I want to be able to parse a string, and look for "tags". For example, I'd like to find the '[color=???][/color]' part of a string, not care what comes after the equals, not care what's inbetween the tags and not care where the are in the string, as long as they are *somewhere* in the string, and that 'color=' has a hex value after it. Here is a sample string:

```
mystring = 'Hello, [color=#0026FF]world[/color]!'
--                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: [Parsing general-purpose markup languages that allow nesting **is not possible using regular expressions.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) - This looks like that famous forum styling markup language of which I don't remember the name -- any chance anyone has written a proper parser for it yet?

Comment: I've seen it on phpBB, and I think it's called phpBB Code Markup. Not sure if it has a name. I don't think anyone has wrote a parser yet. Darn! Any other way I can look for those tags in Lua?

Comment: How complicated is your markup? What are the exact rules? What do you want to do when you've found them? [Patterns in the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1)

Comment: Please note that Lua patterns are not regexes; they have different syntax, and patterns are weaker than regex.

Comment: @paramagnetic: phpBB is highly idiosyncratic. I wouldnt be surprised it the actual parser in the forum engines were the big mess of regexes you are trying to avoid :)

Comment: Do you want to parse any [bbCode](http://www.bbcode.org/reference.php)?

Comment: @Eamonn How on earth did you come to that conclusion? I found at least 3 separate _lua_ parsers for bbCode within 5 minutes of googling. Not that the absence of one would be much of a problem anyway, parsing bbCode is incredibly easy. Assuming you went in knowing nothing about parsers, this still shouldn't take more than a couple of hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Patterns in the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1)

First step, split the tokens:

```
function split_tag(s, i)
  i = (i or 0) + 1
  local j = s:sub(i, i)
  if j == "" then
    return
  end
  j = s:find(j == "[" and "]" or ".%f[[\0]", i) or #s
  -- In Pre-5.2 Lua use %z instead of \0 in the pattern
  return j + 1, s:sub(i, j)
end
for k, v in split_tags, 'Hello, [color=#0026FF][bold]world[/bold][/color]!' do
  print(('%q\n'):format(v))
end
```

Thus, you get your input string

```
'Hello, [color=#0026FF][bold]world[/bold][/color]!'
```

split into

```
"Hello, "
"[color=#0026FF]"
"[bold]"
"world"
"[/bold]"
"[/color]"
"!"
```

Standard parentheses matching algorithm left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says "malformed pattern (missing ']')"

Comment: But `i` is type number

Comment: @Deduplicator, I'm using Lua version 5.1

Comment: @hjpotter92: Damn, too much refactoring without testing.

Comment: It works! I get "q" being printed out constantly, so I'm not sure what the :format(v) does to the code...